# <a href ="somewebsite.com"> takes to localhost/somewebsite.com , Why?

Tags: html, href

I want  to open somewebsite.com , but it goes to localhost/somewebsite.com , why its taking relative path.

Comment: What happened when you prefixed it with www, as www.somewebsite.com? Or http://www.somewebsite.com?

Comment: It worked when i appended with http://

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Your link is missing the protocol at the start of the URL: `http://` for pages not using SSL, `https://` for pages securing data transfer using SSL.

If you want a link that works in either scenario, you can use `//` instead of the fully qualified protocol.

Comment: Hi you really replied in 40 secs after i posted question. Cool !!! I got answer in 40 seconds.

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: If I use ``//``, it took me to ``https//`` instead of ``https://``. Why?